# Why is my variable still "uninitialized"?

Tags: c#

```
string foo;
try
{
    foo = "test"; // yeah, i know ...
}
catch // yeah, i know this one too :)
{
    foo = null;
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo); // argh ... @#!
}
Console.WriteLine(foo); // but nothing to complain about here
```

Besides it's not BP (catching-routing) - but this is the best isolation I can get.
But I get nice waves telling me "danger, danger - might be uninitialized".
How comes?

**Edit:**
Please do not suggest "Simply put a `string foo = string.Empty;` at the 'declaration'". I'd like to declare it, but just do the assignment on time!

Comment: Assign a null, this is efficient and will appease the compiler, then get rid of the catch entirely.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth i've mentioned that this is an isolated example, didn't i? i have to use the catch in my *real* scenario, because i have some other code in there :)

Comment: yes you did but you have yet to provide a solid argument for not initializing it with null beforehand. You stated in another comment that you didn't want to do that. Manojlds answer is likely the reason, the finally is considered out of the try scope so the MSDN docs entry still stands.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth it's just against my nature to workaround the cool feature of splitted declaration and assignment/initialization - at that time i'll do this, i could argue: "why is there still splitted declaration and assignment/initialization ?? i could do a 'foo'-assignment at the start" ... :)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth btw ... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/for-best-results-dont-initialize-variables.html

Comment: Different situation. Does that performance improvement apply for method-scoped variables?

Comment: maybe the runtime will opt that out - but i believe, since i saw the spec, it won't ... so ... you will have 2 writes (regardless of the actual value) of pointers ... the write of the null-pointer is needless and *might* cost some cycles ...

Comment: But there you enter the world of micro-optimisation, an optimisation that might be completely negated 100 fold by an unwanted or unnecessarily slow garbage collection run :-) Still, interesting stuff.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth yep, i know. but, as i've mentioned before: i would like to know what i am doing - otherwise i would be stuck in a scheme, which, applied to this scenario, might hurt performance in others - and therefore i am asking for the "why", "how", ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some background from the C# specification (5.3.3.14):

> For a try statement stmt of the form:
>
> try try-block finally finally-block
>
> (...)
>
> The definite assignment state of v at the beginning of finally-block
>   is the same as the definite assignment state of v at the beginning of
>   stmt.

Edit Try-Catch-Finally(5.3.3.15):

> Definite assignment analysis for a try-catch-finally statement (...)
>   is done as if the statement were a try-finally statement enclosing a
>   try-catch statement
>
> The following example demonstrates how the different blocks of a try
>   statement (§8.10) affect definite assignment.

```
class A
{
  static void F() 
  {
    int i, j;
    try {
      goto LABEL;
      // neither i nor j definitely assigned
      i = 1;
      // i definitely assigned
    }
    catch {
      // neither i nor j definitely assigned
      i = 3;
      // i definitely assigned
    }
    finally {
      // neither i nor j definitely assigned
      j = 5;
      // j definitely assigned
    }
    // i and j definitely assigned
    LABEL:;
    // j definitely assigned
  }
}
```

I just thought of an example that shows the problem better:

```
int i;
try
{
    i = int.Parse("a");
}
catch
{
    i = int.Parse("b");
}
finally
{
   Console.Write(i);
}
```

Comment: but i have try-block,catch-block,finally-block

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I added quotes for Try-Catch-Finally.

Comment: btw, the example is misleading! the spec states: "try-finally statement enclosing a try-catch statement" ... but yes - now it is clear ... `finally` is just out of phase/scope ... thanks!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I just added an example of my own that hpefully shows the problem

Comment: which explains why `finally` is designed to be out of scope ... yes ... but - i could simple do another try-catch inside the catch (to catch that) :) the spec is btw really good (i just needed to think about this few sentences some minutes)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change the first line to  `string foo = null` or initialize as needed. As far as the compiler is concerned, there might be an exception before the foo is intialized in try block and the catch may not happen as well.

Comment: The important part being the lack of guarantee on the catch, if the complier cannot guarantee it opts for the safe path - error or warning.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth any pattern, for my scenario, to ensure the catch for the safe path? btw could you give me any spec on "the lack of guarantee on the catch"? that would be really nice!

Comment: Is there really a case where an exception is thrown, the catch block isn't executed, but the finally block is?

Comment: @andreas Never mind I spoke before thinking it through. The try- catch docs warn of this when the variable is used outside the try, but don't state anything about using the variable in the finally. I would guess it is the same argument. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @kookiz I only know of the cases where the finally block doesn't run.

Comment: is maybe `finally` ignoring both the `try` and `catch` blocks, since it doesn't know how much of either might have executed? I don't see any reason why the `finally` should complain if the second `Console.WriteLine` call doesn't. any scenario where `foo` is uninitialized in the `finally` block, it will be uninitialized after it as well.

Comment: @Sahuagin that was exactly my thought!

Comment: @sahuagin unless you initialize it in the finally ;-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth which it isn't. the point is either both should complain or neither should (in the code example given).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth which could overwrite the actual value of my variable - but i cannot do a check against the variable, as it'll give me the "might not be initialized"-error

Comment: nope, this answer/path/examplantion is (sadly) not *true* :( it follows the path of "catch might not happen", which is not the main-issue here - rather it's "`finally` is out of scope" ... but which is/can be connected

Comment: @Sahuagin Ah didn't spot the second call on my mobile.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem probably is that there is the case where *both* the `try` and `catch` throw exceptions. In that case, the `finally` should still be reached, but with an uninitialized `foo`. Since in that case, the rest of the code will not be reached (the exception that was thrown in the `catch` block takes us out of the method after the `finally`), this does not present a problem for the code after the `finally`. That code can only be reached if either the `try` or `catch` blocks ran.

Since there is always the case that every single assignment to `foo` threw an exception, and since in that case the `finally` block will always run anyway, there is always the possibility of `foo` being uninitialized.

As far as I can tell, the only way around this is to provide an initialization value for `foo`.

Comment: i agree. but: (i believe that) the compiler would get that :) ... the real issue here is "`finally` is out of scope"

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `string foo` at class level it will solve the problem

**EDIT :** or

```
string foo = "default";
try
{
    foo = "test"; 
}
catch (Exception) 
{
    foo = null;
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo); 
}
```

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair then initialize `string foo` before `try catch`

Answer (score -2):

try

```
string foo = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
string foo = null;
try
{
    foo = "test"; // yeah, i know ...
}
catch // yeah, i know this one too :)
{
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo); // argh ... @#!
}
Console.WriteLine(foo); // but nothing to complain about here
```