# In C#, why is a variable not definitely assigned at the beginning of a finally block?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I don't understand why the following code produces an error. Normally I can figure things out from the language specification, but in this case I don't understand the language specification.

This isn't causing problems in my code, by the way, I just want to understand the language.

Example:

```
bool success;
try
{
    success = true;
}
catch
{
    success = false;
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine(success); // ERROR: Local variable 'success' might not be initialized before accessing
}
```

This behavior appears to be true of all versions of C#, but the quotes below are from [C# Language Specification 5.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all).

**Section 5.3.3.14** Try-finally statements

> The definite assignment state of v at the beginning of finally-block is the same as the definite assignment state of v at the beginning of stmt.

Here "beginning of stmt" refers to the beginning of the entire try-finally statement, i.e. just before `try`.

**Section 5.3.3.15** Try-catch-finally statements

> The following example demonstrates how the different blocks of a try statement (§8.10) affect definite assignment.

```
static void F() {
    int i, j;
    try {
        goto LABEL;
        // neither i nor j definitely assigned
        i = 1;
        // i definitely assigned
    }
    catch {
        // neither i nor j definitely assigned
        i = 3;
        // i definitely assigned
    }
    finally {
        // neither i nor j definitely assigned
        j = 5;
        // j definitely assigned
    }
    // i and j definitely assigned
  LABEL:;
    // j definitely assigned
}
```

Can anyone explain why `success` (in my example) or `i` (in the language spec example) are not definitely assigned at the beginning of the finally-block?

Comment: I can only hazard a guess, and hence a comment instead of answer.. While you see only simple, single statements in your try / catch blocks.. in reality, plenty could happen in between, and hence there is no guarantee that the assignment in `try` or `catch` block will ever occur. Basic (too simple may be) example - `ThreadAbort` exception may occur as you enter `try` block, but before the assignment.. and same with `catch` block. If CLR still makes best effort to execute your `finally` block, there is no guarantee that either try or catch executed successfully.

Comment: This question has been asked before, but I don't think any of the answers sufficiently explain the behaviour given in the  C# specification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732670/why-is-my-variable-still-uninitialized

Comment: What am I missing here? It seems the answer is "because the spec says so".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple reason is - There is no guarantee that the code in `try` or `catch` block will ever execute, before `finally` block.

`ThreadAbort` Exception can happen inside the `try` block, but before assignment executes.

Runtime code executes after exception is thrown but before code in `catch` blocks executes (Search for how exception handling works in .Net or "Structured Exception Handling").

Hence, code in try and catch block may never execute, before execution of `finally` block.

Comment: As soon as you said "ThreadAbort exception" it clicked for me. I was not considering exceptions originating from outside the code I was looking at. I don't actually know what situation would cause two exceptions to be thrown in my contrived example—once immediately after entering the try-block, then once immediately after entering the catch-block—but I can see now how the language cannot guarantee that any of the code in my try-block or catch-block has run before the finally-block executes.

Answer (score 2):

1. As Vikas said, exceptions can happen inside catch block too, passing control to the finally without running the whole catch block.  There's no guarantee that either of the assignments actually completed.
2. Why design the language to make it easier to write bad code?  Good code will catch only specific exceptions, or catch and log all but then rethrow the ones it doesn't recognize.  Only bad code that catches and ignores all exceptions can even run into this case.

Besides, the fix is incredibly easy.