# Why does a try/finalize block does not throw CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable compilation error?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

Why is it that `variant_1` does compile while `variant_2` fails with `CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable`, as expected ? I imagined maybe finally initializes unassigned variables to their default, but I do not see that happening.

I ran this code with `.NET Core 3.1`

```
static string variant_1()
{
    string str;

    try
    {
        str = "grrr";
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    return str; //no problem ?
}

static string variant_2()
{
    string str;

    try
    {
        str = "grrr";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return str; //does not compile: `CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable`
}
```

Comment: @Selvin: did not understand your comment

Comment: So there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755949/in-c-why-is-a-variable-not-definitely-assigned-at-the-beginning-of-a-finally-b?noredirect=1), which explains why "try" and "catch" might not be executed, but your "finally" is empty, so this isn't a full answer.

Comment: @Veverke differences ... it is hard to find differences with first look

Comment: If an exception occurs before the assignment to `str` takes, control flow is never going to reach that `return` statement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: should not the same apply to the try/finally variant ?

Comment: compiler doesn't know it there is some code before  `str = "grrr";` in try ... but it assume that there is ... and if it would throw str would never assign but method would hit return ... in finally version it would not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine that something bad can happen here:

```
static string variant_2()
{
    string str;

    try
    {
        //Something bad happens
        str = "grrr";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return str; //does not compile: `CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable`
}
```

Maybe it's a `ThreadAbortException`. Maybe it's something else. What happens? Control flow enters the `catch` and then the *remainder of the function executes*. `str` was never assigned.

For the `finally` case though, if any exception occurs, control flow may enter the `finally` but then it *exits the method*. `return` is never going to be encountered. The only path through that `try`/`finally` block that continues to the `return` is one where no exception occurs in the `try` part and so the assignment that occurs inside it must have been made.